# Should a Factory ever be generated per request?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm working with AutoFac to do some DI. I think I've got a decent grip on things, but just ran into a question I had with my code and thought I'd check:

```
public class AutofacRegistrations
{
    public static void RegisterAndSetResolver()
    {
        // Create the container builder.
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register the Web API controllers.
        containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //  Only generate one SessionFactory ever because it is expensive.
        containerBuilder.Register(x => new NHibernateConfiguration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();

        //  Everything else wants an instance of Session per HTTP request, so indicate that:
        containerBuilder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InstancePerApiRequest();
        containerBuilder.Register(x => LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)).InstancePerApiRequest();

        //  TODO: I don't THINK I should actually be making a DAO factory per API request. I think the whole point of a Factory is to make them once.
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<NHibernateDaoFactory>().As<IDaoFactory>().InstancePerApiRequest();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<StreamusManagerFactory>().As<IManagerFactory>().InstancePerApiRequest();

        // Build the container.
        ILifetimeScope container = containerBuilder.Build();

        // Create the depenedency resolver.
        var dependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;
    }
}
```

You can see that I am registering an `NHibernateDaoFactory` and a `StreamusManagerFactory` as `InstancePerApiRequest`. This doesn't feel right to me because I think creating a Factory is supposed to be a relatively expensive endeavour and they should probably be `.SingleInstance()` similiar to the `ISessionFactory`.

However, my NHibernateDaoFactory has a dependency on Session:

```
...

public NHibernateDaoFactory(ISession session)
{
    if (session == null) throw new NullReferenceException("session");

    Session = session;
}

public IErrorDao GetErrorDao()
{
    return ErrorDao ?? (ErrorDao = new ErrorDao(Session));
}

....
```

and my ManagerFactory has a dependency on the DaoFactory:

```
...

public StreamusManagerFactory(ILog logger, IDaoFactory daoFactory)
{
    if (logger == null) throw new NullReferenceException("logger");
    if (daoFactory == null) throw new NullReferenceException("daoFactory");

    Logger = logger;
    DaoFactory = daoFactory;
}

public IErrorManager GetErrorManager()
{
    return ErrorManager ?? (ErrorManager = new ErrorManager(Logger, DaoFactory.GetErrorDao()));
}

...
```

This leaves me having to create new factories per request. Is this correct?

Comment: Per *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* (the famous GoF book), An *abstract factory* is often used as a *singleton*. I don't know [tag:autofac] very well (never used it), but I'm sure it has a way of specifying a "singleton" *lifestyle* (Ninject has it as "InSingletonScope").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got one thing to say on your code:

#### Your Comments add close to no value!

your code is littered with comments and empty lines

> ```
> //Create the Container Builder
> var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
> ```

The comment is in fact almost exactly the same as the code below. And it's not only there, it's the same with every comment in the `AutofacRegistrations` you posted.

---

Other than that, if your factory has a dependency on `Session` you maybe did something wrong. Instead you could try to pass the `Session` to the already instantiated singleton factory, when calling the `GetErrorDao()` Function.

That would instead look something like that:

```
public IErrorDao GetErrorDao(Session session)
{
     return ErrorDao ?? (ErrorDao = new ErrorDao(session));
}
```

this would decouple both your `NHibernateDaoFactory` and your ManagerFactory and let them be free to use a singleton pattern instead. Which in turn greatly reduces the stress your application puts on the system.

You'd need to cascade this up the Dependency Chain, but that's a small price to pay to have a decoupled Factory Instance for all Requests / Sessions instead of one for each Session.
You'd thus need to modify your GetErrorManager too:

```
public IErrorManager GetErrorManager(Session session)
{
    return ErrorManager ?? (ErrorManager = new ErrorManager(Logger, DaoFactory.GetErrorDao(session)));
}
```

Comment: The comments were simply taken directly from the AutoFac documentation... https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration but I appreciate your concern. I do understand that I should be speaking about 'Why' and not just being explicit, but I didn't feel the need to remove comments from other's documentation.

I'll consider inverting control of Session all the way up, but I thought the whole point of a Factory was to obfuscate that logic from others. That said, it does look like bubbling it up would be quite beneficial. I'll work on it.

Comment: @Sean the point of a Factory is to have a way to instantiate classes of a certain Interface Type, without needing to know the Class itself / have to care which implementation it actually is.